# List of Scala.js classes actually linked into fastOpt.js/ fullOpt.js?

Tags: scala.js

I'm writing an sbt plugin that creates a JS file from a specific StaticAnnotation type; instead of including all annotations found on the classpath, I would prefer to only emit annotations on classes that were actually linked by fastOptJS / fullOptJS. Can I leverage the Scala.js linker tools or sbt plugin to this end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The Scala.js Tools API (the linker tools) offers a data type called [`Analysis`](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-tools/latest/#org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.analyzer.Analysis) which contains everything you need.

You can construct an `Analysis` with [`Analyzer.computeReachability`](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-tools/latest/index.html#org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.analyzer.Analyzer$@computeReachability%28semantics:org.scalajs.core.tools.sem.Semantics,symbolRequirements:org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.analyzer.SymbolRequirement,allData:Seq[org.scalajs.core.ir.Infos.ClassInfo],allowAddingSyntheticMethods:Boolean%29:org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.analyzer.Analysis). You have to give it the appropriate [`ClassInfo`](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-ir/latest/#org.scalajs.core.ir.Infos$) for the .sjsir files on your classpath.

This has been done in [the callgraph sbt plugin](https://github.com/lionelfleury/scala-js-call-graph) which, although still under development, shows how to construct an `Analysis` for an sbt project:
https://github.com/lionelfleury/scala-js-call-graph/blob/065506bf9a9c12ccc54fed056fed878e6f18b328/sbt-scalajs-callgraph/src/main/scala/ch/epfl/sbtplugin/CallGraphPlugin.scala#L28-L49

This particular implementation selects the `Analysis` *after* optimizations have been performed (unless the program does not link, in which case it falls back to the analysis *before* optimizations are performed). Depending on your use case, you might prefer one or the other, but it is more likely that you want the version *after* optimizations.

Once you have an `Analysis`, you can simply list its `classInfo` members, and filter out those for which `.isNeededAtAll` is false. Again, depending on your case, you want to use more refined tests, such as `.isAnySubclassInstantiated`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed explanation. One question though: how do I get a core.tools.logging.Logger from an sbt.Logger?

Comment: Like this: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/sbtplugin/Implicits.scala (although, now that I see that, we should probably not expose those things as implicits ^^)